# Econ SE open source Journal Proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Based on [this](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1813/8815) suggestion, I'm taking initiative for proposing the first Economics.Se open source Journal.

The standards for entry are undetermined, but right now I just want to see if there is interest in putting something together.

For a start, I'd want a minimum of 3-4 contributors (including myself) with a non-specific focus within the field of economics. Entries I am suggesting should be about 1500 words including an abstract and small literature review.

What are your thoughts on the idea? are you interested in getting involved?

Comment: I suppose I have a short and small extension of a model I could contribute. How would this work exactly? Would we publish under our real names or usernames?

Comment: Real names if you want it to be legit. If the community proposes that we should keep it under usernames I'd be up for that. It'll be a PDF though.

Comment: That's fine by me.

Comment: This seems fine, but why not the open-sourced paper idea?

Comment: I wouldn't mind contributing.

Comment: I don't know enough to contribute, but I would be an avid reader of such! =)

Comment: Is there any precedent of other SE's starting journals? What would the standards be like? Would it be published on the SE website or elsewhere like arxiv?

Comment: @pafnuti not that I know of. it would just be stored on a cloud site.